# Error in Mongodb with native Node.js Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a homework exercise, and the following code returns a document of "null" prematurely (before the cursor is exhausted), and crashes the program at the next value since I have already closed the database:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var query = {};

    var cursor = db.collection('data').find(query).sort({'State' : 1, Temperature : -1});

    var currentState = '';
    var lastState = '';

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(doc == null) {
            //console.log(doc.State)

            return db.close();
        }

        if(doc != null){           
            currentState = doc.State;
            if(currentState != lastState){             
                var query2 = {"_id" : doc._id};
                doc['month_high'] = true;

                db.collection('data').update(query2, doc, function(err,updated){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.dir("Successfully Updated " + updated + "documents");
                });

            }
            lastState = doc.State;
        }
    });
});
```

**HOWEVER!!** if I limit the batchsize of the cursor to 10 or 20, by changing the one line of code to:

```
var cursor = db.collection('data').find(query).sort({'State' : 1, Temperature : -1}).batchSize(20);
```

The code executes perfectly without errors. What's going wrong???

Comment: Update: Through a great deal of guess and check, I have deduced the maximum batchSize() I can have without the db crashing is exactly 493. I have no idea why.

Comment: You're calling `db.close()` before all of your `update` calls have completed and called their callbacks.

Comment: `cursor.each` is deprecated. Use `cursor.forEach` instead. Note that it takes an `endCallback` as the second argument.